# After install, how to get ubuntu to boot from HDD?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, system-installation

How do i get my pc to know that ubuntu is on a certain hdd to boot it? Currently its installed on a hdd with 2 partitions- does that matter?

Tried going into system BIOS and picking the hdd with no luck.

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue. On a standard installation it is the boot loader's job to "point" to the right partition. It is installed in the top priority boot device by default. Have you followed the standard procedure to install? Did you do anything special/out of the ordinary? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Go through a LiveBoot session, then go through the steps [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If that doesn't work you can do `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd comment to get this information, but I guess I need 50 reputation to comment? Seems silly.

Anyway, this seems likely to be a problem with GRUB. What happens when you boot? We really need more information.

Some things to try:

1. Unplug all peripherals from USB ports except for mouse and keyboard (in case it's trying to boot from, say, your plugged in phone or, more likely, the live USB that you used to install ubuntu).
2. Remove any CDs from the drives, as well.
3. Make sure that the HDD is set to be the first boot device in the BIOS

When you boot, your computer does the following:
   1. Looks for the BIOS
   2. Looks at your boot devices, IN THE ORDER THEY ARE SPECIFIED IN THE BIOS. This is where you want to make sure your HDD is set to be the first in the list
    3. If it finds something it thinks it CAN boot from (say, a USB drive like I said above) it will try to boot from it. If in fact it CAN'T boot from that, it will just hang at a black screen.

Keep this in mind as you try to troubleshoot it, and please get us some more information if these steps don't help.

Comment: This is probably better as an answer, anyway.